# How to get the fields from listagg in quotes?

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

Consider the table STUDENTS:

```
---------------------
|Sr.No|    Name     |
---------------------  
| 1   |    Jon      |
---------------------
| 2   |    Rob      |
---------------------
| 3   |    Bran     |
---------------------
```

Using below query we get:

```
select listagg(Name, ',') within group (order by Name) from STUDENTS
```

From this we will get :

```
Jon,Rob,Bran
```

How do we get something like

```
"Jon","Rob","Bran"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

this should do the job

```
select listagg('"'||Name||'"', ',') within group (order by Name) from STUDENTS;
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin !!! Can you suggest how it can be done with single quotes as well like 'Jon','Rob','Bran' ?

Comment: Got it select listagg(''''||Name||'''', ',') within group (order by Name) from STUDENTS;