# String formatting using LISTAGG in Oracle. Escaping single quote ` ' `

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

How can I format the output of listagg in Oracle to produce output(every field in the single quote) as `'student1', 'student2', 'student3'`.
I have gone through documentation and other question on listagg but can't find much.
[SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

```
SELECT LISTAGG(student_name,',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY student_name)
from students
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to manually add the first and the last quote but the middle one, you can use `', '` to join the strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the fields from listagg in quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860335/how-to-get-the-fields-from-listagg-in-quotes)

Comment: It is not a duplicate of this as we can format the string in any way by this answer except single quote easily. We have to use `two single quotes` as given in answer to get one as an output. 
I tried putting ' \' ' to get the desired output.
It was a simple question of escaping the single quote in string `'`.

Comment: Yes, the post I cited is not one to one.  This might be a better one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854040/how-to-use-listagg-to-return-rows-prefixed-with-quotes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT LISTAGG('''' || student_name || '''',',') 
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY student_name)
FROM students;
```

or using `ENQUOTE_LITERAL` function:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL(student_name),',') 
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY student_name) AS r
FROM students;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1a7867148188b133ca1a3f8d663e7378)**

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job. You need to escape the `'` in the query.

```
SELECT LISTAGG('''' || student_name || '''',', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY student_name)
FROM students
```