# SQL: How to generate a result that updates columns based on the data?

Tags: sql

Suppose we have a database (I'm using Snowflake) which keeps updating books based on which country it was released from.

| Date | Booke Name | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22-03-2023 | book1 | US |
| 22-03-2023 | book2 | CA |
| 22-03-2023 | book3 | RU |
| 22-03-2023 | book4 | US |
| 22-02-2023 | book5 | US |

Is there a way we can query it such that I get a total count in a different column without having to hardcode the countries in a for loop or something?

I'm expecting the output to be something that's grouped by date and has separate columns for each country count, something like this:

| Date | US_Count | CA_Count | RU_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: What's your database engine?

Comment: @gotqn Snowflake database. I'll update it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I got this right, you can use the GROUP BY clause and the COUNT() function.

```
SELECT 
Date,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'US' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS US_Count,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'CA' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS CA_Count,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'RU' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RU_Count
FROM 
  books_table
GROUP BY 
  Date;
```

https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/count-sql-function

Comment: Thank you for this! is there no way to do this other than hard coding the country? suppose in the future the list of countries becomes exponentially large.

Comment: try this out : SELECT 
  'SELECT Date, ' || 
  LISTAGG('COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = ''' || Country || ''' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "' || Country || '_Count"', ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Country) ||
  ' FROM books_table GROUP BY Date' AS dynamic_sql
FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM books_table)
ORDER BY 
  Country;
ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860335/how-to-get-the-fields-from-listagg-in-quotes

Comment: Anis , Thanks for the response
It just prints this as output:

SELECT Date_id, COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'CA' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "CA_Count", COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'US' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "US_Count" FROM ems_rpt.tca.trades GROUP BY Date